# graphene fails on import with EnumBadKeyError

Tags: python, python-2.7, graphql, graphene-python

While attempting a basic tutorial on Graphene, I have encountered an early problem that doesn't seem to be coming up for others, specifically the initial import fails.

Python 2.7.16, Graphene 2.1.8, Six (1.12.0). I've updated all installed packages via pip.

```py
python -m graphene

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 163, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, _Error)

File "F:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(mod_name)  # Do not catch exceptions initializing package

File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\graphene\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .types import (

File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\graphene\types\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .schema import Schema

File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\graphene\types\schema.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .typemap import TypeMap, is_graphene_type

File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\graphene\types\typemap.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .enum import Enum

File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\graphene\types\enum.py", line 70, in <module>
    class Enum(six.with_metaclass(EnumMeta, UnmountedType, BaseType)):

File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 827, in __new__
    return meta(name, bases, d)

File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\graphene\types\enum.py", line 33, in __new__
    enum = PyEnum(cls.__name__, enum_members)

File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\enum.py", line 199, in __init__
    raise EnumBadKeyError(key)
enum.EnumBadKeyError: Enumeration keys must be strings: OrderedDict([
 ('__module__', 'graphene.types.enum'),
 ('get_type', <classmethod object at 0x031DADB0>),
 ('__doc__', '\n    Enum type definition\n\n    Defines a static set of values that can be provided as a Field, Argument or InputField.\n\n    .. code:: python\n\n        from graphene import Enum\n\n        class NameFormat(Enum):\n            FIRST_LAST = "first_last"\n            LAST_FIRST = "last_first"\n\n    Meta:\n        enum (optional, Enum): Python enum to use as a base for GraphQL Enum.\n\n        name (optional, str): Name of the GraphQL type (must be unique in schema). Defaults to class\n            name.\n        description (optional, str): Description of the GraphQL type in the schema. Defaults to class\n            docstring.\n        deprecation_reason (optional, str): Setting this value indicates that the enum is\n            depreciated and may provide instruction or reason on how for clients to proceed.\n    '),
 ('__init_subclass_with_meta__', <classmethod object at 0x031DAD90>),
 ('__eq__', <function eq_enum at 0x031DBD70>)]
```

Comment: Can't reproduce on Python 2.7.6: `No module named graphene.__main__; 'graphene' is a package and cannot be directly executed`.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit of 'but I said I was going to give up and take a break' digging, turns out the [enum](https://pypi.org/project/enum/) package that was interfering with whatever graphene was doing with its own enums.  Removal of the package resulted in imports working as expected.